# C# MYSQL - ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - Same Query Different Results

Tags: c#, mysql

In my test app; I get positive row count as result when I run this query repeatedly, even when there is no change.

```
insert into  test (k,v) values ('testkey',123) 
on duplicate key update v=values(v);
```

The query works as expected in MySQL Console and MySQL Workbench. I get 1 for the first insert and 0 for the successive calls.

However when I try in my C# test app I always get 2 even when nothing changes inside the row.

Any ideas? Am I missing something while setting up the connection?

This is my test table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `k` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `v` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `icol_UNIQUE` (`k`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this is my tiny test code:

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection("Database=mydb;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=mypass;CharSet=utf8;"))
    {
        con.Open();
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into  test (k,v) values ('testkey',123) on duplicate key update v=values(v)", con);
        var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Console.WriteLine(rows); // rows is always 2
    }
```

NOTES:

- I am using MySql .Net Connector 6.9.8
- All database charset/collation
  settings are utf8

Comment: In the documentation it states "(The effects are not identical for an InnoDB table where a is an auto-increment column. With an auto-increment column, an INSERT statement increases the auto-increment value but UPDATE does not.)" so that may be related. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @AndyNichols My problem is not about auto increment id. The problem is in the number of affected rows returned in case of no-change. And the problem is specific to the application. It works without problems in console.

Comment: After one year. I still have the same issue. 
- Running "on duplicate key update" query with .Net Connector always returns positive integer even when the row does not change. 
- However same query works as expected in MySQL Console and MySQL Workbench and returns "0 rows affected" when there is no change 

This seems like a bug to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found the solution after reading the manual below
https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-net-en.pdf

There is a connection option called Use Affected Rows, UseAffectedRows

Its default value is set to false.

And the description says:

> When true, the connection reports changed rows instead of found rows.
>   This option was added in Connector/Net version 5.2.6.

When used; Doesn't set the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag when connecting to the server

It seems like MySQL Workbench and MySQL Command Line don't use the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag during connection, where the MySql .Net Connector uses it by default.

From INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE document at
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and
>   0 if an existing row is set to its current values. If you specify the
>   CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag to mysql_real_connect() when connecting to
>   mysqld, the affected-rows value is 1 (not 0) if an existing row is set
>   to its current values.

**Solution:
Add this to the connection string**

```
Use Affected Rows=true
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me (the same option for MariaDb).