# Detect if MySQL rows were inserted in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I have a C# program which attempts to insert data into a MySQL database. The data may already be in the database, in which case it simply overwrites it.
Example:

```
MySqlConection dbConnection = ...; // Setup connection
int numCustomersToUpdate = 3;

String query =
    "INSERT INTO customer_regions (customer_id, region_id)
    VALUES (1, 205), (2, 314), (3, 151) // 3 customers
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE region_id = VALUES(region_id)";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbConnection);

int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (rowsAffected == numCustomersToUpdate)
{
    // Data either did not exist before and was inserted,
    // or already existed and overwritten
}
else
{
    // Error inserting data
}
```

The problem is that if the data was overwritten, `rowsAffected` is 0, which is considered an error. How can I consider it a successful SQL execution regardless of whether the data was inserted or overwritten?

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42050951/6138713) which is most likely to solve your issue.

Comment: Ignore the return value altogether. If it doesn't throw an exception it did an INSERT or UPDATE. There is no need to check `rowsAffected`.

Comment: @mjwills, Thank you, this seems to be the simplest method. Is there any case where eg. only some rows are inserted or updated, and no exception is thrown, but the only way to know would have been to check the number of rows affected?

Comment: With that SQL, no.